# Ruby 'gets' behaving weird?

Tags: ruby

I am writing this program to manage dotfiles and gets doesn't seem to behave like it usually does, and I was unable to trace down relevant information through Google.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

@filename = ''

unless $*[0].nil?
  # Storing filename (and adding dot) 
  @filename = "."+$*[0].to_s
else 
  # No filename given, exit and print to STDERR
  abort("No filename specified")
end


@file_path = File.expand_path("~/#{@filename}")

if File.exists?(@file_path)

  print "Enter something: "
  gets
  puts $_

end
```

However, the program crashes at the "gets" line like this

```
$ ruby ./link.rb bash_profile
Enter something: /Users/krystah/repos/backpack/dotfiles/link.rb:24:in `gets': 
No such file or directory - bash_profile (Errno::ENOENT)
  from /Users/krystah/repos/backpack/dotfiles/link.rb:24:in `gets'
  from /Users/krystah/repos/backpack/dotfiles/link.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Seems the line numbers were left out when pasting, but line 24 in the error message does indeed equal the gets-line ins the File.exist clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets):

> **gets(sep=$/) → string or nil**
>   **gets(limit) → string or nil**
>   **gets(sep,limit) → string or nil**
>
> Returns (and assigns to `$_`) the next line from the list of files in `ARGV` (or `$*`), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line.

You do have things in `ARGV` so `gets` will try to read from a file called `'bash_profile'` and then complain that there is no such file. You probably want to be a little more explicit about where you're reading from:

```
print "Enter something: "
$stdin.gets
puts $_
```

---

This is actually a pretty interesting question. `gets` (and a lot of the other function-ish things in [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html)) are generally intended for one-liners so their behaviors are specialized in surprising ways. Once you understand their intended purposes, the strange behavior is less surprising.

Comment: Great insight, thanks a bunch. :) I actually tried to find information on how to explicitly choose gets source, but to no avail. Anyhow, this solved it, so again, thanks!